# How to find a path from one vertex to another in a tree using breadth first search?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a BFS that returns a path from `a` to `b` in form of a list of vertices. I am implementing this BFS on a tree so I know it will be the shortest path if I can find one. However, so far my research has only led me to find BSF algorithms that search and find nodes, rather than return a path.

The input that I am dealing with is an adjacency matrix of the Minimum Spanning Tree. I must take this and find path from one point to the other.

Comment: More details?  Please?  This feels a little like you haven't put *too* much effort.  But the basic idea is just store a list of all nodes visited in the BSF search, and then that is the path.

Comment: @mackycheese21 I understand that it may seem that way. I have spent quite a bit of time and effort on this but the problem is that I can't really try and implement something until I figure out what it is that I am implementing. Regarding what you said, doesn't a BFS visit every node, so this sequence would not be a path from vertex a to b.

Comment: Sorry! Hmm.  Take a look at Dijkstras Algorithm or A*.  It depends.  Are your connections weighted?  BFS is probably not what you want to use.

Comment: @mackycheese21 In the original graph the edges were weighted but then I found a Minimum spanning tree from that. So now, there is just one unique path from any two vertices and I just need an algorithm for finding it. So the tree can be treated as if it was unweighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use BFS to solve this, to trace the path from source to destination you need to store the parent of each node visited. Here's a sample BFS without optimizations.

```
import java.util.*;

public class bfs {

    static class Node {
        Node parent;
        int x;

        Node (int x) {
            this (x, null);
        }

        Node (int x, Node parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.x = x;
        }

        void trace () {
            if (parent == null) {
                System.out.print (x);
            } else {
                parent.trace ();
                System.out.print ("->" + x);
            }
        }
    }

    static void bfs (int start, int goal, int[][] adj) {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<> ();

        list.add (new Node (start));

        while (!list.isEmpty ()) {
            Node cur = list.remove (0);

            if (cur.x == goal) {
                cur.trace ();
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < adj[cur.x].length; i++) {
                    if (adj[cur.x][i] == 1) {
                        list.add (new Node (i, cur));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[][] adjacency_matrix = {
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
        };
        int start = 0;
        int goal = 4;

        bfs (start, goal, adjacency_matrix);
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that I think of it it is not absolutely necessary that I use a node searching algorithm. I simply need to find a path.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this non recursively

Comment: Yes it can be done without recursion but you will need to store an array or a list in the Node.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra or A* is probably what you want to use.  It depends, though.  What you seem to be describing is a pathfinding algorithm, not a node search.

Comment: That makes sense. I got so many hits for BFS when googling that I felt I was on the right path